# Windows defender flags an app but Norton says it's fine

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender, norton-internet-security

I'm trying to download Lychee Slicer from Mango3D.io.  I followed their suggestion by telling windows defender to allow it to download.  Then I scanned it with Norton.  Norton said both the website and app are safe.  Should I believe Norton over Windows Defender?

Comment: For the love of god get rid of Norton...

Comment: I would be extra careful with sites telling their users to "please whitelist the installer in your antivirus software". Especially when the software isn't something that could _look_ like a virus, i.e. encryption software, remote desktop stuff, etc. Why would a 3d slicer software (what does it do) that triggers antivirus?

Comment: @simon, they didn't ask me to whitelist anything they just said to skip the warning from windows defender smart screen.  Honestly that may be the same thing. I don't know why perhaps the process by which a new piece of software becomes recognized by microsoft is a long one.  Or it's spyware.

Comment: Did you install it? What did the warning actually say, that it found some kind of virus or was it simply a warning about the executable not being signed or signed but with an unknown certificate?

Comment: Norton sucks. Scan the app with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.

Comment: Why would you just compare a few single programs and not use a portal as suggested in the accepted answer? https://superuser.com/a/1578644/910769

Comment: @user1258361 From what I've seen Norton doesn't suck *any more*.  Norton 360 seems to have generally positive reviews.

Comment: Simon the warnings I got were from smart screen.  I don't have them up anymore but it was something to the effect of "smart screen does not recognize this software", which has been suggested by others to mean it's just not something it's seen before.  MANICX100's suggestion of VirusTotal.com showed green checks for pretty much everything so  I went ahead and installed it.  Then I scanned everything again with Norton (which has one of the top ratings on PCMag.com) and it said it was clear.  I think we're probably safe at this point.  I was just nervous because I don't usually see those warnings

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would scan the offending binary (if not too big) on [Virus total.](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) This will automatically provide a report from over 60 different anti virus products and if they detect it.

Then you can decide who to trust :)

Comment: This site did clear both the source website and the downloaded installer.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the SmartScreen warning message was along the lines of

> Windows SmartScreen prevented an unknown application from running.  Running this application might put your PC at risk.

... all that means is that SmartScreen doesn't recognize the download as one that is known to be safe.

It does *not* mean that SmartScreen has determined the download to be malicious.  You would get a more strongly worded message if that were the case.

Answer (score 4):

Which AV will you trust is completely up to you. If you think that the app is OK you can whitelist it in windows Defender. (Myself I don't prefer Windows Defender, I have disabled it).

Another thing, you can see what kinds of threats can Windows Defender block. Open Powershell as Administrator and run `Get-MpThreatCatalog | Format-List *` to see all threats. The list is huge, Microsoft has improved Defender (Also more annoying) much.

Virus Total is a great online platform to scan binaries for viruses (already mentioned in other answer), still if the file is to big, it is hard to upload, so I prefer [IRMA](https://quarkslab.com/irma/) as an offline alternative.

Comment: How do I disable Windows Defender on 10? I am happy as a clam with Norton these days.

Comment: @JustJohn Open Windows Security > Virus and threat protection and click Manage settings and turn off Real-Time Protection and other things. Basically if you use Norton, Windows Defender should let Norton manage things.

Comment: thanks. I turned off everything I could find there. cheers.